# Do functions defined inside an if block get taken out at compile time? Will a top-level if get run at compile time?

Tags: elixir

I have a function that I, for security reasons, would only like to be available in dev environments. If I do something like this:

```
if Mix.env() == :dev do
    def some_func() do
        do_sensitive_stuff()
    end
end
```

When I compile my project, will the code in the `if` block not get compiled? More generally, can I run code at compile time like this? Or would I need something like a macro?

Comment: Yes, and yes. The function will be compiled and injected into the beam if and only the condition is truthy. This is extremely easy to check, btw.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Thanks! Could you maybe explain how the compiler figures out what conditions it can check at compile time to see if it should optimize the branch away? (Maybe in answer too so I can accept your answer formally? )

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin, *This is extremely easy to check* -- Decompiling the .beam file?

Comment: @7stud decompilation of BEAM is [not that hard](https://dev.to/mudasobwa/unveil-erlang-code-of-your-elixir-project-kcj), but I was talking about compiling the above and trying to call `some_func/0` from different envs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elixir is actually kinda DSL on top of Erlang VM. Domain is extremely wide, but still. Nearly everything in Elixir is *a macro*.

`def`, `defmodule`, even `defmacro` itself is [indeed a macro](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/1d1702810b991008fcff674ca7cc52f794356cf7/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L4138).

There is no magic in how the compiler works. On the first stage, it walks through the source code and converts everything into AST. When it sees a macro, it expands it (macros return AST) and injects the AST returned in the place where macro happened to appear.

One might have a code on the top level of the file, inside `defmodule`, inside `defmodule` and `def` etc. Everything will be expanded until no further expansion is possible.

When the compiler sees `if`, it expands [`if`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/1d1702810b991008fcff674ca7cc52f794356cf7/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L3090-L3112) macro, still, there is no magic.

Now you probably might wonder why there is something “runnable” left after the compilation phase ever. When the compiler sees `def`, or any other macro that returns AST back, it stores that AST (and then this AST is actually converted into BEAM files.)

As an example, you might try this code:

```
defmodule Test do
  IO.puts("I am compiling")

  def run, do: IO.puts("I am running")
end
```

If you’d try to compile this, you’ll see the former message appeared during the compilation stage. The latter would appear only when one explicitly calls `Test.run/0` after compilation.

Comment: Ah, I see. So, since the `if` is at the top-level, it's condition will get evaluated at compile-time, right? (If you meant this with "it executes `if` macro...", could you distinguish between macro expansion and execution?)

Comment: It’s always expanded, sorry my misleading wording.